# Show the convergence of $X_k$ and $Y_k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, optimization, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

Consider two sequences $(X_0, X_1, \dots)$ and $(Y_0, Y_1, \dots)$, where $X_k\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y_k \in\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose two  continuous nonlinear functions $f$ and $g$, so that the following recursions hold:

\begin{align*}
X_{k} &= \arg\max f(X_k, Y_{k+1})\\
Y_{k+1} &= g(Y_k, X_k)
\end{align*}
with $Y_0$ given. Here, $\arg\max$ returns the maximizer $X_k$ of function $f(X_k, Y_{k+1})$.

It is known that for fixed $X_k=X, \forall k$, $Y_{k}$ converges to $Y$ as $k$ goes to infinity. Besides, all $X_k$ and $Y_k$ are nonnegative.

How can I show that both $X_k$ and $Y_k$ converge and under what conditions?

Comment: Are the $X_i, Y_i$ real numbers? What are $f$ and $g$? Any two functions? And what is $\arg \max$?

Comment: $X_k$ and $Y_k$ are both $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ and $g$ are both known nonlinear functions, and $\arg\max$ is the the argument that gives the maximum value from function $f$, meaning that $X_k$ is the maximizer of $f(X_k, Y_{k+1})$.

Comment: You should edit your question. People do not want to read comments to get all necessary information.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the question.